# getting json data loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui, for-loop

Hello I’m having some problem:
I some data coming from a JSON file, and I need to write it in a more efficient manner. Basically its working fine, but I will like to put the images in like a nested array or something.

So I just only have to do one image tag call, but the image tag will be bringing in a Set of Images. I don’t want to define image1-image1000 img tags,

I should be able to just put in the images like this:

```
“image”: { image1.jpg, image2.jpg, image3.jpg, image4.jpg}
```

and call it with one  image tag like this

It that possible??? Some guidance will be helpful. Thanks

```
JSON DATA

{   "mygallery": [
            {"image1": " image1.jpg",
            "image2": " image2.jpg",
            "image3": " image 3.jpg",
            "image4": " image 4.jpg",
            “pagename”: “MyGallery”,
    }




JAVASCRIPT CALL

<script type="text/javascript">
$.getJSON('js/gallery.js, function(data){
         $("#main").html('');
         $(data.mygallery).each(function(index, mygallery){
             $("#main").append('<li class="thecontent"><img  src="/_img/' + mygallery.image1 + '"  /><img  src="/_img/' + mygallery.image2 + '"  /><img  src="/_img/' + mygallery.image3 + '"  /><img  src="/_img/' + mygallery.image4 + '"  /><span>' + mygallery.pagename + '</span></li>');
         });
     });



</script>



HTML DIV
<div id=”main”>




</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create something like this which still keep all the `images` and `pagename` inside `mygallery` object.

```
{   
   "mygallery": { images: [
                       "image1.jpg",
                       "image2.jpg",
                       "image3.jpg",
                       "image4.jpg",
                    ],
                   pagename: “MyGallery”
                 }
}
```

This is how you will use it

```
$.getJSON('js/gallery.js', function(data){ 
      $("#main").html('<li class="thecontent">'); 
      var images = data.images;
      for(var i =0;i<images.length;i++){
         $("#main").append('<img src="/_img/' + images[i] + '" />'); 
      }
      //$.each(images function(index, image){ 
      //   $("#main").append('<img src="/_img/' + image + '" />'); 
      //}); 

      $("#main").append('<span>' + data.pagename + ' </span></li> ');
  });
```

Comment: <code>I'm getting it to spit it out like this: <img src="images/alcohol1.jpg,alcohol2.jpg,alcohol3.jpg,alcohol4.jpg"></code>

Comment: @john - Take a look at my edited answer added the required code to loop through images and append the markup.

Comment: to be honest im getting tired up implementing it.

Comment: NO, not me. someone downed all the answer...even the question..grrrrr..i dont even have enough points to vote yet. lol

Comment: How can i write this in a WHILE LOOP & FOR LOOP??..only the image segment??

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding the question, but you can define an array in JSON with square brackets, so for example:

```
{
"myArray":["foo","bar","baz"]
}
```

Comment: So if i have a Array already define like this:
<code>
{ "mygallery": [
   {"image1": " image1.jpg",
   "image2": " image2.jpg",
   "image3": " image 3.jpg",
   "image4": " image 4.jpg",
   “pagename”: “MyGallery”,
 }</code>

How will i write it so that the image part is in an array that still corresponds to the mygallery array name??

Comment: John, that code you're supplying there is actually invalid JSON. The opening square bracket is never closed, an opening curly brace that is never closed and there's an extraneous comma at the end of your JSON object. Also, seriously bro, downvoting people who are trying to help you is a good way to guarantee nobody else will every try to help you again.

Comment: I DID Not downvote, how will i downvote all the answer and even my own question... i dont even have enough puts to vote.

Comment: ok I apologize then. So, are you able to control the format of the json string that you're working with? Because right now that string is busted.

Comment: Maybe in my example above i missed something..i actually type it out from hand and not from my actual code...everything is out putting but my FOR LOOP  or EACH statement is not on point.


I'm back to sqaure one kinds pushing it out like this:
<img  src="/img/' + gallery.images +'"  />


which is pushing my data out like this:

<img src="/img/1.jpg,2jpg,3.jpg,4.jpg,5.jpg">

Answer (score 0):

Use a nested each loop (assuming the structure stays consistent with what you're showing:

```
$.each(data.mygallery,function(index,mygallery){
  var $li = $('<li />'{ class: 'thecontent' }).appendTo('#main');
  $.each(mygallery,function(name,image){
    $('<img />',{ src: '/_img/'+image }).appendTo($li);
  });
});
```

Otherwise, you are probably better off making the images an array instead of an object. So instead of:

```
"images": { "imgae1" : "image1.jpg", "image2": "image2.jpg" }
```

it looks like:

```
"images": ["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", "image3.jpg"];
```

*(unless there is a reason for the key value)*

Comment: So...who went through and did a mass down-vote and didn't give anyone a reason as to why?

Comment: I agree, it's sort of annoying to have a downvote terrorist on the loose.